# PyQt5 GUI crashes when traversing iglob iterator on large directory

Tags: python, file, user-interface, pyqt5

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

import os
from os import scandir, walk
from time import sleep
from glob import iglob, glob

class FileRead(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(FileRead, self).__init__(parent)

        self.resize(600, 400)

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()

        self.loader = QProgressDialog("File read progress", "stop showing progress", 0, 100)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.loader)

        self.curfile = QLabel("CURRENT FILE")
        self.layout.addWidget(self.curfile)

        self.dirs = QLabel("DIRECTORY LISTING")
        self.layout.addWidget(self.dirs)

        self.btn = QPushButton("read files")
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.wrapper)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.btn)

        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.filenames = []

    def wrapper(self):
        self.file_names('.')
```

This method: process_subdir, is what causes the most problems.

```
    def process_subdir(self, path, toplevel=True):
        txts = iglob(path + "/**/*.txt", recursive=True)
        for t in txts:
            print(t)  

    def file_names(self, start_path = '.'):
        dirs = glob(start_path + '/*/')
        d_len = len(dirs)

        files = glob(start_path + '/*.txt')
        f_len = len(files)

        total_len = d_len + f_len

        toplevel = [(d.split('\\'))[1] for d in dirs]
        # setting the text to empty for now
        self.dirs.setText("\n".join(toplevel))

        ctr = 0

        for f in files:
            ctr += 1
            if (f.endswith('.txt')):
                self.filenames.append(f)
                self.curfile.setText(f)
                self.loader.setValue(((ctr)/total_len)*100)
            sleep(1)

        for idx, d in enumerate(dirs):
            ctr += 1

            write_str = ""
            for n_idx, n_d in enumerate(dirs):
                n_d = (n_d.split('\\'))[1]
                if (n_idx < idx):
                    write_str += n_d + "(done)\n"
                elif (n_idx == idx):
                    write_str += n_d + "(in progress)\n"
                else:
                    write_str += n_d + "\n"
            self.dirs.setText(write_str)
            self.loader.setValue(((ctr)/total_len)*100)
            self.process_subdir(d)
            sleep(1)

        write_str = ""
        for d in dirs:
            d = (d.split('\\'))[1]
            write_str += d + "(done)\n"
        self.dirs.setText(write_str)

        print(self.filenames)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ...
```

What I am attempting to do in this program is read through all the files in a certain directory and check their file extensions. For this section of code, it is checking for `.txt` files. The method I use for this is to allow the user to click a button, and scan a hardcoded (for now) directory for the text files. It works for smaller directories, and doesn't end up crashing, but when I attempt to run the program and parse larger directories, the GUI tends to crash. Something I also noticed is that when I run the program on a smaller directory, I can no longer interact with the GUI. Is there a way to 
a) prevent the GUI from crashing when parsing large directories?
b) allow the GUI to still be interacted with even when the file parsing is going on?

Answer (score 0):

The solution I used was to use QThreads instead of running a for loop for every d in dir. This way the GUI event loop isn't blocked and it doesn't look like the GUI crashes. In addition the program runs faster as a whole.